# How to get first and last row against one foreign key from a table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've a situation where there is one ticket history table. it saves all the actions done against a ticket. how to write a query which will return the first record and the last record against specific ticket.

[image]

for example in the above table I've one ticket with id 78580. I want to get the first row and last row based on date column.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by ticket_id order by action_when asc) as seqnum_a,
             row_number() over (partition by ticket_id order by action_when desc) as seqnum_d
      from tickets t
     ) t
where seqnum_a = 1 or seqnum_d = 1;
```

Comment: one more question is it possible if i can use this in join ... because I want to filter it on one ticket and then extract the first and last row

Answer (score 2):

Use min and max to get first and last date, grouped by ticket id.

```
SELECT ticket_id, min(action_when), max(action_when)
FROM table_name
GROUP BY ticket_id;
```